Fantasy TV series with a male protagonist who uses a bow and arrows and has a hawk/falcon/eagle type bird companion
I watched this on TV in the late 80s or early 90s.
It was a fantasy TV series (most probably) where the male protagonist uses a bow and arrows and has a hawk/falcon/eagle bird companion. At the end of episode, his bird companion flies away to distance or to him, drops a feather, and he picks up his quiver full of arrows and went on his quest/adventure.
Sorry for not providing a clear description; I was 5-7 years old at the time.

This is the TV-movie, The Archer: Fugitive from the Empire (1981).

The hero is given his mentor's bow (the Heartbow) which chooses its new owner when passed on. It fires arrows that blow up like grenades, but can only be wielded by the one chosen to wield her. The hero is a member of a nomadic tribe wiped out by the Draikian Empire's forces. He attempts to find the wizard Lazar-Sa who might be able to help him. He is joined by a thief looking for adventure and cash, and the daughter of a goddess, Estra, looking to revenger herself on Lazar-Sa for crimes against her mother.

The protagonist is Toran, prince of the nomadic Hawk Clan. He wields a magical 'Heartbow' and is on a quest to find the wizard, Lazar-Sa, who is imprisoned in a location unknown to himself and Toran.
Lazar-Sa uses a hawk as his eyes and ears in the outside world and as a conduit for telepathic communication with Toran. The hawk isn't really Toran's companion; their interactions are infrequent and brief.


The Archer: Fugitive from the Empire (1981)

Toran's main companion in the film is a rogue named Slant, whom he meets after setting out on his quest. A woman named Estra also travels with them for a while.


The Archer: Fugitive from the Empire (1981)

In the closing scene, Toran and Slant have yet to find Lazar-Sa, but Lazar-Sa (speaking through the hawk) encourages them to keep searching for him and the hawk drops a feather that turns into a bundle of arrows which Slant places in Toran's quiver.
According to the Wikipedia page, this was the pilot for a planned TV series that never materialised, hence the open ending.
The film is available to watch at the Internet Archive, but here's a trailer.




Thank You very much from bottom of my heart. I am 99% this is the one I watched. I will check everything related to it. Thanks again.
