Fantasy movie from the late 70s or early 80s in which an assassin kills a king in his tent
When I was young (approximately 1979 to 1982), my father recorded (on a Betamax) a fantasy movie that fascinated me to the point that I watched it every weekend for many months in a row.
The primary identifying element was a quote from the beginning of the show that had an assassin killing a king in his tent. After the deed, the assassin was able to scream in the king's voice "My son's killed me!" This then became the basis of the movie, with the son on the run trying to avenge his father. Pretty standard fantasy elements with him gathering a diverse group to help him and winning the day at the end.
I tried using the movie-quote databases but they don't find this quote. Anyone familiar with this?

This is the TV-movie, The Archer: Fugitive from the Empire (1981).

The hero is given his mentor's bow (the Heartbow) which chooses its new owner when passed on. It fires arrows that blow up like grenades, but can only be wielded by the one chosen to wield her. The hero is a member of a nomadic tribe wiped out by the Draikian Empire's forces. He attempts to find the wizard Lazar-Sa who might be able to help him. He is joined by a thief looking for adventure and cash, and the daughter of a goddess, Estra, looking to revenger herself on Lazar-Sa for crimes against her mother.

The protagonist is Toran, prince of the nomadic Hawk Clan (the guy in the middle in the image below).
Around twenty minutes into the film, there's a scene where he gets into an argument with his father, King Brakus, in front of several witnesses. Around five minutes later into the runtime, Brakus is mortally wounded by assassins while otherwise alone in Toran's tent. Toran enters the tent shortly afterwards and is briefly knocked out by a blow from behind delivered by one of the assassins, who then cries out...

My son's killed me!

... before ducking out through the back of the tent and leaving Toran to take the blame for Brakus' murder.
Just before Brakus dies, he makes Toran promise to find the wizard, Lazar-Sa, whose guidance Brakus believes Toran will need to succeed him as king. Toran subsequently sets out on a quest to find Lazar-Sa and picks up a couple of companions along the way.



You can watch the whole film at the Internet Archive, but here's a trailer.




If so, it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/289466/fantasy-tv-series-with-a-male-protagonist-who-uses-a-bow-and-arrows-and-has-a-ha/289467#289467

Were you able to find this based on the quote? What did you use?

@SDH - I submitted this as an answer to another user's story-ID question a few weeks ago, and watched the film itself, so your description of the king's assassination immediately rung a bell with me. I originally found the film by googling some keywords based on the other user's description, which brought up a Reddit thread where this was submitted as an answer to another story-ID question with a similar description.

@LogicDictates It is not quite as good as I remember...

@SDH - Yeah, as I noted in the other answer, it was a failed TV pilot, and therefore had an unsatisfying "Thank you Mario! But our princess is in another castle!" type ending. Being made-for-TV probably also limited the budget as well as the level of violence/gore that was allowed to be shown. The most notable thing about it for me was some early turns from actors who later went on to be in bigger and better things, like Marc Alaimo from Star Trek: Deep Space Nine and Belinda Bauer from Robocop 2. I also never expected to see George Kennedy in a sword & sorcery flick.
